# r's rep() feature in python

Tags: python

I am relatively new to python and still figuring out stuff. I wanted to check if there is an equivalent of **r's** **rep** command in python to replicate entire vector and not each element. I used numpy.repeat but it only repeats each element given times, is there a way to tweak it to repeat the entire vector?

example:

```
y=np.repeat(np.arange(0,2),3)
print(y)
array([0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1])
```

expected output using r's rep

```
 a<-c(0,1)
 rep(a,3)
 0 1 0 1 0 1
```

Comment: See https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.tile.html#numpy-tile

Comment: @PM 2Rings, well i thought the example would clear any doubts, but i have removed string from the title.

Comment: @PM2Ring wow just what I needed. Thanks a ton

Comment: @PM2Ring if you can add that as an answer I could accept!

Comment: Sometimes where a R user solves an issue using`rep()` a Numpy user would use broadcasting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm no expert in R by any means but as far as I can tell, this is what you are looking for:

```
>>> np.tile([0, 1], 3)
array([0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1])
```

Answer (score 1):

your expected output is not in python (even though that's what you want) but if i try to translate it basically you want something that transforms lets say `[0,1,2]`
to `[0,1,2,0,1,2,0,1,2 ...]` with any number of repetitions

in python you can simply multiply a list with a number to get that:

```
lst = [0,1]
lst2  = lst*3
print(lst2)
```

this will print `[0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]`

Comment: that's great info, but this doesn't work on numpy arrays, right?

Comment: no numpy arrays will return an array that has each element multiplied by 3... as i said you didn't say what your expected output in python is so there was no way to know for sure how to answer your question ...

Answer (score 1):

Straight from the docs. [np.repeat](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html) simply repeat the element present in the iterable to the number of times specified in the argument.

Other than what has already been posted is use of [repeat](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.repeat) and [chain](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) of itertools

```
from itertools import repeat, chain
list(chain(*(repeat((1,2),3)))) # [1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2]
```